Is there a way to turn these photos into useable anchored Brushes in sculpting mode?
i was wondering if there is a way for me to get these drawings (ornaments/spikes) into a useable brush for sculpting, with the anchored way of useing a brush, since i really want to use them as texture, but they have to be pretty much exactly the same as the photos (either one, not sure which one is the most suatble for the brush) - Does anyone know if that is possible?  
Best regards and thank you in advance! :)

Use Photoshop, Krita or Gimp to create a new 2048*2048 file, import the second image, invert it and blur it with a 2 to 6 pixels ratio, save as PNG RGB.
In Blender go to sculpt mode, select draw brush, clic on New Texture button, click on its texture button (icon with two little "sliders"), load the PNG image, set draw method to Anchored, Area Plane, Constant Falloff, 0.15 Strenght.
This is the result on a 1.6 Milion Sphere, you can play with the Auto Smooth value too.


thank you so much! it works perfect :)
